# Caret train() mlp missing values

Tags: r, machine-learning, training-data

I'm trying to train a multi layer perceptron for non linear regression on a dataset but it keeps giving me this error :

```
Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

I tried doing it again with a R dataset to see if my data was the problem but I keep getting the error and i have no idea why.

I already tried adding or removing tuneGrid, trControl, even linOut. 
It will always give me constant results for some reasons.

```
    library(datasets)
    library(MASS)
    library(caret)
    DP = caret::createDataPartition(Boston$medv, p=0.75, list = F)

    train = Boston[DP,]
    test = Boston[-DP,]
    colnames(train) = colnames(Boston)
    colnames(test) = colnames(Boston)

    mlp = caret::train(medv ~., data = Boston, method = "mlp", trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3),
                       tuneGrid = expand.grid(size = 1:3), linOut = T, metric = "RMSE")

    Yp = caret::predict.train(mlp, test[,1:13])
```